# The meaning of "leap" here

Tags: word-meaning

> It was spring. Sodden ground, smell of earth. The wind beat through
>   twigs, gave off a greenish odor like struck flints. Coltsfoot in the
>   ditches; furious dabs of tulips stuttering in gardens. Slanting rain.
>   **Clock hands leapt to pellucid evenings**. The sky riffled like cards in
>   a chalk-white hand.

*The Shipping News by Annie Proulx*

What does the verb "leap" mean here? How can clock hands leap to the certain time?

**EDIT**: In this sentence, I had trouble understanding why time (I understood that clock hands indicate time) would leap to pellucid (brighter opposed to dark) evenings, particularly in spring. From some of the comments I realized that the verb 'leap' isn't a physical leap but an expression that there is longer day light in spring than winter time. As TRomano suggested in his comment, daylight saving (this might mean 'leap' as 'going ahead') helps the spring time to have brighter evenings. For example how much light left at 6 o'clock in winter vs. in spring. Thank you all for the helpful comments.

Comment: IMHO, it describes the spring time. In springtime, days become longer, and when the clock hands "go up", say from 6 pm to 9 pm, they "leap" into "pellucid evenings". The meaning is probably that while in winter the evenings are darker and are muddled with rain, sleet, etc, in spring they become more "transparent", "airy". Her language is poetic.

Comment: "Spring forward, fall back": We set the clocks ahead an hour. Daylight Saving Time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it involves interpreting literature, which is open to multiple interpretations,  and in particular one that employs [a particularly compressed and cramped](https://books.google.com/books?id=jHp8VHqgCmQC&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=Clock+hands+leapt+to+pellucid+evenings.+The+sky+riffled+like+cards+in+a+chalk-white+hand.&source=bl&ots=RLomnW-vN7&sig=i-UIESo8os2x-gKILBVxilIvjgo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio6tiE6vLKAhUB82MKHQJnBmYQ6AEIHzAB#v=onepage&q&f=false) (one wants to say pretentious and (up)chuckable) style.

Comment: @TRomano  I've got it. Thank you. It is very clever of the author.

Comment: How do you know the clock hands **did** anything? (*leapt* as the simple past tense) How do you know something was not done **to** them? (*leapt* as past participle with an implied agent) ; see also the next sentence of the narrative, which is also ambiguous). What makes you think the clock hands are leaping "to the certain time"? What is this time? Is evenings a certain time? Moreover, how do you know they are not 'leapt' or 'set' (by, or as by, human hands) in conjunction with the evenings or to keep up with the evenings?

Comment: @GoDucks - I find her style beautiful in that book, exactly because she leaves so much space for the reader's imagination.

Comment: As an English learner, I can't never fully understand the books written in English without some help. It is sometimes to do with grammar, structure, words, or sentence itself.  I don't care there are different interpretations for the sentence I asked. As long as the answers you give turn on light in my head and make me visualize the passage, I am grateful. Otherwise I would have to read only some kind of textbooks which don't throw any ambiguity at my face.

Comment: The movement of clock hands normally signifies the passage of time. *Leaping* here seems to indicate a certain quality to the passage of time, or it is simply a heightened way to express the passage of time that the writer chose for an unknowable reason (perhaps even unknown to herself). Maybe it's to mean suddenly, perhaps to personify time, ascribing it a motivation to eagerly advance. "Leap to the evening", then, just means that time passes to evening in one of these ways or another. It does not suggest that time is at work abnormally; it does not mean a leap of time occurred.

Comment: @Cop The question focuses on the meaning of *leap* in this context. I don't see how longer days necessarily imply leaping or hands "going up" in any way that shortening days in autumn would not. Couldn't time leap just as well toward cloudy evenings as clear? Unless, she wants to characterize time as being in a hurry to arrive at particularly pleasant evenings, as one denotation of *leaping* involves eagerness. Here, however, perhaps the best of us speculate, but you have a much greater poetic sensibility than I.

Comment: Basically if the OP (that's you, whitecap) know what *leapt* means (usually available from a dictionary), we can't go much beyond [that](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81210/the-meaning-of-leap-here?noredirect=1#comment157550_81210) because the exact meaning of a turn of phrase, or how an author uses a phrase *cannot* be discerned. This author, especially, leaves tons open to interpretation. Furthermore, yes you may have to read literature that employs more accessible, graspable  language  than does this text. This is not easy reading, even for English native speakers.

Comment: @GoDu First, *What does the white whale symbolize* is a different kind of question than *What does the verb "leap" mean here.* Second, standards for comments differ than those for questions. Third, for the most glaring example of literary criticism, see your comment above referencing "a particularly compressed and cramped (one wants to say pretentious and (up)chuckable) style." Fourth, answers in meta with a few upvotes are not policy, even if that answer did proscribe the question, which it does not.

Comment: Your question *would* be better received if you mentioned which dictionary definition(s) of the term you have considered, and state that you would like help figuring out it's meaning in this particular context. For example, do you have a guess, and why do you have doubt (if you can articulate these things).

Comment: @ Jim Reynolds  Thank you, but your answer is more than enough considering various meanings one could gather from all the comments above. All I wanted was to read and enjoy a wonderful English book while learning English. Thank you for helping me appreciate this book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leap here indicates movement forward in time. Clock hands moving forward can most straightforwardly be taken to mean something like *the days move into evenings.*

Likely dictionary senses that may apply in this context include sudden or fast movement, and so the idea that time seemed to pass quickly into eveningtime.